# How to get text and a variable in a messagebox

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

I just need to know how to have plain text and a variable in a messagebox.

For example:

I can do this: `MsgBox(variable)`

And I can do this: `MsgBox("Variable = ")`

But I can't do this: `MsgBox("Variable = " + variable)`

Comment: string concatenation in vb.net uses the ampersand "&"

Comment: Give an example and put it in an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As has been suggested, using the string.format method is nice and simple and very readable.

In vb.net the " + " is used for addition and the " & " is used for string concatenation.

In your example:

```
MsgBox("Variable = " + variable)
```

becomes:

```
MsgBox("Variable = " & variable)
```

I may have been a bit quick answering this as it appears these operators can both be used for concatenation, but recommended use is the "&", source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw(v=VS.100).aspx

maybe call

```
variable.ToString()
```

update:

Use string interpolation (vs2015 onwards I believe):

```
MsgBox($"Variable = {variable}")
```

Comment: Yep, `(String1 + String2)` and `(String1 & String2)` are both fine, but if want to concatenate a String and an Integer, you need `&`. Just ran into this issue today.

Comment: That'd be much more verbose than simply using `&`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Only slightly. Very readable and you could also use string interpolation depending on which .net version you use.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use:

```
Dim msg as String = String.Format("Variable = {0}", variable)
```

More info on [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx#Y0)

Answer (score 0):

I kind of run into the same issue. I wanted my message box to display the message and the vendorcontractexpiration. This is what I did:

```
Dim ab As String
Dim cd As String

ab = "THE CONTRACT FOR THIS VENDOR WILL EXPIRE ON "
cd = VendorContractExpiration


If InvoiceDate >= VendorContractExpiration - 120 And InvoiceDate < VendorContractExpiration Then

MsgBox [ab] & [cd], vbCritical, "WARNING"

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox("Variable {0} " , variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanto to display the count of rows in the excel sheet after the filter option has been applied.

So I declared the count of last rows as a variable that can be added to the Msgbox

```
Sub lastrowcall()
Dim hm As Worksheet
Dim dm As Worksheet
Set dm = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("datecopy")
Set hm = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Home")
Dim lngStart As String, lngEnd As String
lngStart = hm.Range("E23").Value
lngEnd = hm.Range("E25").Value
Dim last_row As String
last_row = dm.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox ("Number of test results between the selected dates " + lngStart + " 
and " + lngEnd + " are " + last_row + ". Please Select Yes to continue 
Analysis")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be as follows :

```
iNum1 = 10
iNum2 = 20
iSum = iNum1 + iNum2

MsgBox ("The sum of " & iNum1 & " and " & iNum2 & " is " & iSum)
```

this will result in The sum of 10 and 20 is 30