# How do you concatenate strings from two TextBoxes?

Tags: vb.net, string, concatenation

for example in this code

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim a As Object
    Dim b As Object
    Dim c As Object

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        a = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        b = Val(TextBox2.Text)
        c = Val(TextBox3.Text)

        TextBox3.Text = a + b

       ' TextBox4.Text = "a + b = c"
    End Sub

End Class
```

How can i make TextBox4.Text show the numbers, (=) sign, and (+) sign i.e.

TextBox1.Text = "2" and TextBox2.Text = "3" and TextBox3.Text = "5"

How can i make TextBox4.Text = "2 + 3 = 5"

(the string not the value)

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: I think he is.  It might look something like this: TextBox4.Text = ""+ a + " + " + b +  " = " + c + ""  <<<Something like this (corrected) to VB concat...

Comment: @FrankTudor when concatenating strings in VB.NET always use `&` as it clearly shows your intention vs. `+`

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings by using either the `&` or `+` operator, like this:

```
TextBox4.Text = TextBox1.Text & " + " & TextBox2.Text & " = " & TextBox3.Text
```

In VB.NET, the `&` operator is preferred for string concatenations, but, as long as you have `Option Strict On`, the `+` operator is just as safe to use:

```
TextBox4.Text = TextBox1.Text + " + " + TextBox2.Text + " = " + TextBox3.Text
```

Alternatively, for more complicated concatenations, like this one, you may find it easier to use `String.Format`, like this:

```
TextBox4.Text = String.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)
```

Comment: I would use & and not + to concatenate... TextBox4.Text = TextBox1.Text & " + " & TextBox2.Text & " = " & TextBox3.Text

Comment: I think + is right....look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630146/how-to-get-text-and-a-variable-in-a-messagebox

Comment: If you want to gain more reputation, I recommend making your answers more explanatory, clear, and thorough.  I've edited your answer to show you an example of what I mean.  I've found that often being thorough and helpful is just as important as being correct.

Comment: @FrankTudor it is not right... look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088053/string-manipulation-with-or-in-vb-net . Your linked question even uses legacy VB6 functions such as `MsgBox` which should be avoided in favor of .NET's `MessageBox.Show()`